# AzureML SDK not working with PyTorch 1.5?

Tags: pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service

Has anyone got PyTorch 1.5 to work with the AzureML SDK (versions 1.11 and 1.12)? torch.cuda.is_available() returns False even on GPU-enabled machines. Exactly the same setup works fine (is_available() is True) with PyTorch 1.3, 1.4 and 1.6. Any pointers welcome. These are the (possibly) relevant parts of my Conda environment file, with the values of pytorch and azureml-sdk varied as required.

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.3
  - pytorch=1.5.0
  - pip:
      - azureml-sdk==1.12.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with PyTorch 1.5 and CUDA and is acknowledged by PyTorch in [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/37212) GitHub issue.

They haven't provided an official solution to the issue, but they recommend either updating old GPU-drivers or making sure you have a CPU-enabled version of PyTorch installed. Since you're not experiencing this problem with other PyTorch versions on AzureML GPUs, GPU drivers don't seem to be the issue, so it's probably the PyTorch installation.

Try installing "torchvision==0.6.0" along with your pytorch=1.5.0. PyTorch's site encourages pairing 1.5.0 with torchvision 0.6.0: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Comment: Thanks - yes, I actually specified torchvision==0.6.0, though I didn't show it in the snippet above. Another option is PyTorch 1.6 which is working fine for me (with azureml-sdk 1.12) once I work around this issue (which applies to 1.6 too) by setting the environment variable as recommended: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/37377